# Add components to a layout created whit qt creator from code

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt-creator

I have a problem setting some components from code to a layout created using qt creator i'm trying to add the components and when i run my window the components doesn't show up here is some code the SlotPLayerWidget is a widget that i created also using qt creator

```
'#include "joinwidget.h"
#include "ui_joinwidget.h"
#include "ui/joingameteamselectionwidget.h"
#include <QDebug>
JoinWidget::JoinWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::JoinWidget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->createPlayersSlots(8);
}

JoinWidget::~JoinWidget()
{
    delete ui;
}

void JoinWidget::on_exitButton_clicked()
{
    exit(0);
}

void JoinWidget::on_startGameButton_clicked()
{
    //start game
}

void JoinWidget::on_mainMenuButton_clicked()
{
    emit mainMenuButtonClicked();
}

void JoinWidget::setPlayerName(QString playerName){
    this->playerName_ = playerName;
}

void JoinWidget::createPlayersSlots(int numberOfPlayers){

    for(int i = 0;i< numberOfPlayers; i++){
        SlotPlayerWidget widget;
        ui->slotPlayersVerticalLayout->addWidget(&widget);
    }

}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You allocate the widgets on the stack in the `createPlayersSlots` and that will destroy the widgets before you can do anything with them, to fix this allocate the widgets on the heap.

LE: As a rule with Qt always allocate the child widgets on the heap (it's easy because you don't have to track every piece of memory, the parent will delete those when it gets deleted) and the top level widget (the widget that doesn't have a parent, the "main window" of your application) you can allocate on stack.